# Disable remote input on Ubuntu/Linux running TeamViewer

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, ubuntu-14.04, teamviewer

I see an option to disable remote input and show a black screen on the remote PC we are connected to in TeamViewer. But I'm trying to do this with a remote Ubuntu and these options are grayed out during the session.

I explicitly set the remote PC's properties(advanced) to disable remote input but that doesn't work either. I'm using latest TV versions and controlling PC is a Windows machine. Is this a feature not available for Linux in general? I read somewhere that it's not available on Mac.

Comment: It is availaible for Linux. What version do you use?

Comment: I use TV 11.0.52520 on Ubuntu 15.04, and it is a combined option in the connection properties, and separate check-boxes in the drop-down in a current connection. I've not checked that they work, but I have no difficulty in enabling them.

Comment: I'm using TV version 11 on both sides (updated), and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I see the options too but theyre grayed out, while the preconfigured settings in PC properties just dont work.